# Not able to cast my class to comparable while using comparator

Tags: java, comparator, priority-queue, comparable

Below is the Request class :-

```
package main.model;

public class Request {
    private static long Id;
    private int floorNo;
    Request(int floorNo){
        setFloorNo(floorNo);
        setId();
    }

    public static long getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public static void setId() {
        Id++;
    }

    public int getFloorNo() {
        return floorNo;
    }

    public void setFloorNo(int floorNo) {
        this.floorNo = floorNo;
    }

}
```

and below is the class having priority queue

```
 public static Comparator<Request> lowerQueueComparator = new Comparator<Request>(){

        @Override
        public int compare(Request o1, Request o2) {
            return (o1.getFloorNo() - o2.getFloorNo());
        }
    };
    public static Comparator<Request> upperQueueComparator = new Comparator<Request>(){

        @Override
        public int compare(Request o1, Request o2) {
            return (o2.getFloorNo() - o1.getFloorNo());
        }
    };


    private PriorityQueue<Request> lowerQueue =
            new PriorityQueue<Request>(lowerQueueComparator);

    private PriorityQueue<Request> upperQueue =
            new PriorityQueue<Request>(upperQueueComparator);
```

When I call below function it returns error that request cannot be cast to java.lang.comparable

```
 @Override
    public void addRequest(int floorNo, Request request) throws Exception {
        if (lowerQueue == null || upperQueue == null || floorRequestMap == null) {
            throw new Exception("Request manager priority Queue implementation not intialised");
        }
        if (request.getFloorNo() >= floorNo) {
            lowerQueue.add(request);//here the error is caused
        } else {
            upperQueue.add(request);
        }
        floorRequestMap.put(request.getFloorNo(), request);
    }
```

Also attaching stack trace for reference

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: main.model.Request cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
        at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUpComparable(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUp(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.PriorityQueue.offer(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.PriorityQueue.add(Unknown Source)
        at main.model.RequestManagerPriorityQueueImpl.addRequest(RequestManagerPriorityQueueImpl.java:36)
        at main.model.ElevatorImpl.addRequest(ElevatorImpl.java:90)
        at main.model.ElevatorControllerImpl.startElevators(ElevatorControllerImpl.java:55)
        at Application.main(Application.java:15)
```

as I have added comparator to priority queue do I still need to implement comparable in request ?

Comment: Note that your comparators would be a bit simpler written as `Comparator.comparingInt(Request::getFloorNo)` (and `.reversed()` on one of them).

Comment: Your code looks okay; have you done a complete clean and recompile?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem and everything should work okay. Is there any place in the code where you might reassign `lowerQueue` or `upperQueue` to a PriorityQueue that you don't supply your comparator? (Maybe add final to those 2 fields for checking)

Comment: Same here, works fine. However, in your stacktrace, `siftUpComparable` is called (instead of `siftUpUsingComparator`) which should not happen when you have set a `Comparator`. Try again after recompiling.

Comment: hi @Matt is this because of IntelliJ ?

Comment: IntelliJ should work fine to compile and run this code. Try [rebuilding the project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiling-applications.html#rebuild_project).